# how to work with vue plugin in nuxt project

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I want to use tailwind typeahead vue plugin in nuxt. i have added the package using `npm install vue-tailwindcss-typeahead` .

then i created a file in plugins folder. tailwind-typeahead.js with following code

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueTailwindcssTypeahead from 'vue-tailwindcsscss-typeahead'

Vue.use(VueTailwindcssTypeahead)
```

and included the plugin file in nuxt.config.js

```
{ src: './plugins/tailwind-typeahead.js' }
```

But i am getting this error

```
   This dependency was not found:                                                                                   friendly-errors 01:44:37
                                                                                                                 friendly-errors 01:44:37
* vue-tailwindcsscss-typeahead in ./plugins/tailwind-typeahead.js                                              friendly-errors 01:44:37
                                                                                                                 friendly-errors 01:44:37
To install it, you can run: npm install --save vue-tailwindcsscss-typeahead
```

for reference here is the link of package

```
https://github.com/basarozcan/vue-tailwindcss-typeahead
```

Comment: have you try to make it as a client side only plugin? `{ src: '~/plugins/tailwind-typeahead.js', ssr: false },`

Comment: Yes i tried this now and there is same issue, its not working

Comment: please check the package is installed successfully, and also check the path to your `tailwind-typeahead.js`

Comment: i can see the package in package.json file as well tailwind-typeahead.js is in plugins folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do have a typo in your plugin: `vue-tailwindcsscss-typeahead`.

You probably meant to write `vue-tailwindcss-typeahead` .

The rest is fine and it's the way to go if you want your code to be globally available in your Nuxt app. If you only want it local, import it in the component itself.